# fortran "Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)"

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am learning fortran and encountered a problem with a program I am writing.

The program is below:

```
PROGRAM mymain
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: a, g1
    EXTERNAL f
    PRINT *, "value of a"
    READ *, a
    g1 = f(a)
    PRINT *, a, g1
END PROGRAM mymain

CONTAINS

 INTEGER FUNCTION f(x)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: x
    f = x*x
    RETURN
 END FUNCTION f
```

When I tried to run the program, I got the following error:

```
xfunc.f90:2.14:
PROGRAM mymain
              1
exfunc.f90:17.8:

CONTAINS
        2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)
```

I am not sure how to proceed. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I addition to @ja72's solution using a module (which I also would prefer), this is what I think you are trying to do... The `CONTAINS` statement defines that an **internal** function follows. Internal functions cannot be used outside their scope (the main program/subroutine/function) and have direct access to all variables in that scope. Your code would then read:

```
PROGRAM mymain
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: a, g1
    PRINT *, "value of a"
    READ *, a
    g1 = f(a)
    PRINT *, a, g1

CONTAINS                      ! <-- The CONTAINS statement must come before
                              !     END PROGRAM

    INTEGER FUNCTION f(x)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: x
        f = x*x
        RETURN
    END FUNCTION f

END PROGRAM mymain
```

Don't mix it with an **external** function, which would look like:

```
PROGRAM mymain
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: a, g1
    INTEGER :: f              ! <-- You need to declare the return value of 
                              !     an external function when using IMPLICIT NONE
    EXTERNAL f
    PRINT *, "value of a"
    READ *, a
    g1 = f(a)
    PRINT *, a, g1
END PROGRAM mymain

INTEGER FUNCTION f(x)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: x
    f = x*x
    RETURN
END FUNCTION f
```

Note the missing `EXTERNAL` statement in the first version and the missing `CONTAINS` statement in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MODULE XFUN
CONTAINS
INTEGER FUNCTION f(x)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: x
    f = x*x
    RETURN
 END FUNCTION f
END MODULE XFUN

PROGRAM mymain
    USE XFUN
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: a, g1

    PRINT *, "value of a"
    READ *, a
    g1 = f(a)
    PRINT *, a, g1
END PROGRAM mymain
```

It compiles fine with me